# need suggestion regarding formula for web-based game

Tags: functions

I am developing web based game in which using lots of formulas to achieve different things. I am using the formulas below. Is there any better way to make these formulas more robust and dynamic like using calculus or any other approach to make them smaller and accurate etc?

$$\mathbf{Basic\ Building\ Cost}=300\text{ gold}+\frac{3}{2}(\text{# of acres}) + (0.1\text{ wood})(\text{# of acres})(\text{science})$$

OR

**Armory** – Stores weapons and armor
$$\mathbf{Cost\ to\ build} = (\text{coal mine cost})+(.5\text{ iron})(\text{# of acres}) + (.5\text{ steel})(\text{# of acres}).$$

Sorry didn't know about the proper tags.

Comment: You could do a bit of factoring. E.g., in the second formula, $$\text{cost to build}=\text {coal mine cost}+(.5)(\text{acres}) (\text{iron} +\text{steel})$$

Comment: @pirzada Welcome to math.SE. Please look through [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) on how to ask a question. Your question lacks focus, does not specify the criteria of improvement of your formula, thus making it difficult to properly answer. The question as is is likely to be closed as either non constructive, or of topic. The title of the question is not indicative of what the question is about either.

Comment: What do you think is the problem with these formulas? Any computer built in the last ten years can store millions of such formulas in memory.

Comment: What does "more robust" mean?

Comment: How can we determine whether the formulae can be made more accurate unless you tell us precisely what you want them to do?

Comment: Please don't put things like "to all experts" in the title. All questions here are to all experts, and whoever else may be able to answer them. Titles should be specific to the question.

Comment: @joriki , I am sorry for not asking question properly. My page has almost 1000 line of code involving different formulas and and what I posted was small part. I will compose another question detailing what I want. Sorry for any inconvience.

Comment: @pirzada: I get the impression that you misunderstood my comment. It wasn't directed in general at posting too much (in fact I agree with some of the other commenters that you posted too little); it was directed specifically at using forms of address like "to all experts" in the title that are in no way specific to the particular question and therefore do not contribute to the function of the title, which is to summarize the question.

Comment: @joriki , I understand.

Answer (score 1):

As a computer programmer, I don't think that's expensive in terms of computing time. I would go with that "formula". Also easier if you decide to change it in the future.